# Introduction to Analysis: The Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

The following is a problem from Arthur Mattuck's book, "Introduction to Analysis." Page 265.

> Assume $f(x)$ integrable on $I$. Prove $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is continuous on $I$

How would I pursue such a problem? I know a function is called integrable on an interval if it is defined and bounded on that interval and it satisfies given epsilon greater than zero, $L_f(P) \approx U_f(P)$, for all $P$ such that $|P| \approx 0$.

If a function is integrable, it doesn't necessary mean it's continuous though.

This is what confuses me. The only thing that comes to me is that I have to show that for some mesh, the $\sup f$ and $\inf f$ in that mesh is epsilon close to one another and then somehow show that these $\sup f$ and $\inf f$ in that mesh are epsilon close to the sup and inf of f on the neighboring mesh.
Is that one way to approach the problem?

Thanks for reading and Thanks in advanced for your feedback.

Comment: It's not $f$ that shall be shown to be continuous, it's the integral of $f$. So given the integrability of $f$, can you show that $F(y) - F(x) = \int_x^y f(t)\,dt$ is small when $x$ and $y$ are close?

Comment: @DanielFisher, Then how would I go about it? Would I just have to apply the definition of continuity and then show it's continuous on the interval?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is
$$
F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\, dt.
$$
You evaluate $F$ by plugging in a number for $x$.  For instance
$$
F(b)=\int_a^bf(t)\, dt.
$$
Just because $f$ is not continuous does not mean $F$ is not.  So, you must remember the definition of continuity for an arbitrary function.  Given an $\epsilon>0$, you need to find a $\delta>0$ so that 
$$
\left|\int_a^xf(t)\, dt -\int_a^{x+\delta}f(t)\, dt\right|<\epsilon.
$$
Using properties of integrals, this becomes
$$
\left|\int_{x+\delta}^xf(t)\, dt\right|<\epsilon.
$$
This will show that $F$ is right continuous.  Showing left continuous, use $x-\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

For a (bounded) integrable function $\;f(x)\;$ in $\;[a,b]\;$ , we have that

$$\left|\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx\right|\le(b-a)\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$$

So

$$\left|\int_x^yf(t)dt\right|\le|y-x|\sup_{t\in I}|f(t)|$$

So for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ it is enough to choose

$$\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{\sup_{t\in I}|f(t)|}$$

in the definition of continuity.